# Puzzle from Ecole 42 evaluation

Tags: puzzle

[image: puzzle]

This is Evaluation game 2 for Ecole 42. I'm stuck with this one in my mind. Is there any solution or suggestion for this one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got stuck in this one too. I wonder if this could be a good solution, but can't test it...

f0  - {if red turn left / forward / if blue f1 / f0 }

f1 - {forward /if red turn right / if blue f0 / f1}

like a zig-zag and the blue box do the shift of the turn side...

Answer (score 5):

f0 - {if red turn right / forward / if blue f1 / f0 }

f1 - {forward /if red turn left / if blue f0 / f1}

Comment: Do not forget, that even in the first (initial line) we also touch the blue star, so the solution of Aramayis is correct, as the program has to switch (to `f1` in this case), and at the end of the line left turn is adequate.